# Ng-show not updated in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have two lists of data which are displayed depending of a selected value (language). When i change the language, ng-show is not updating correctly.

I already tried to call $scope.apply() but it doesn't work.

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IpkpOs9mIyv8vlbQX1gN?p=preview)

```
$scope.languageChanged = function() {
  console.log('change' + vm.currentLanguage);
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-show` expects an expression, not a string, so you don't need the interpolation double braces.

Incorrect: `ng-show="{{translation.language === vm.currentLanguage}}"`

Correct: `ng-show="translation.language === vm.currentLanguage"`

Answer (score 3):

@Hugo Wood is correct with the solution for ngShow problem. I can propose one more solution which might be a little bit cleaner. You can to use filters to render necessary items in the first place instead of hiding/showing:

```
<h1>Selected</h1>
<div ng-repeat="translation in vm.translations | filter:{language: vm.currentLanguage}">
  <div>{{translation.language}}:
    <input ng-model="vm.translations[$index].text" /> show: {{translation.language === vm.currentLanguage}} 
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<h1>Not Selected</h1>
<div ng-repeat="translation in vm.translations | filter:{language: '!' + vm.currentLanguage}">
  <div>{{translation.language}}:
    <input ng-model="vm.translations[$index].text" /> show:{{translation.language !== vm.currentLanguage}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/F35yrDv9HcV6hChIDBkZ?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the way you are providing the expression to ng-show. Remove the '{{' and try. Here is an updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vHk0dgzImzY5Gyf0uZ2X?p=preview) on top of what you  provider.

```
<div ng-repeat="translation in vm.translations" ng-show="translation.language === vm.currentLanguage">

<div ng-repeat="translation in vm.translations" ng-show="translation.language !== vm.currentLanguage">
```